# topology defined on the set $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: general-topology

What is the topology defined on the set $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ of functions $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that allows us to talk about convergence of sequences in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: You are allowed to talk about convergence of sequences in any topological space whatsoever.

Comment: well, there are many topologies on that set. What do you have in mind, exactly?

Comment: The way you write it, the product topology might come to mind (though it ignores the topology on the exponent)

Comment: I'm asking what topology is being considered on the set of real functions when we talk about, for example, convergence of a power series.

Comment: That set contains arbitrary, even nonmeasurable functions, so I'd consider it too large for, say, convergent power series. A nicer set for those kinds of questions would be for instance $C(\mathbb R)$, the set of all continuous functions $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$. There you can use the topology of locally uniform convergence, that is, $f_n\to f$ if for all compact $K\subset \mathbb R$, $\sup_{x\in K}|f_n(x)-f(x)|\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

A common topology to use in this context is the so called $L^p$-norm.  In particular, for $p \in [1, \infty]$, we define the norm
$$
\|f\|_{L^p(\Bbb R)} = \left(\int_\Bbb R |f(x)|^p\,dx\right)^{1/p}
$$
with the additional definition
$$
\|f\|_{L^\infty(\Bbb R)} = \mathrm{ess} \sup_{x \in \Bbb R} |f(x)|
$$
[(definition of $\mathrm{ess} \sup$)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Essential_supremum_and_essential_infimum).  The catch with these metrics is that our analysis is limited to those functions for which the norm in question is well defined and finite.

In such topologies, we state that $f_n \to f$ iff $\|f_n - f\|_{L^p(\Bbb R)} \to 0$.

Two other common topologies are [the weak and weak* topologies for vector spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology).

Comment: The first two topologies you mentioned are not really for the _whole_ set $\mathbb R^{\mathbb R}$, are they?

Comment: If I have a sequence $a:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$, a function $\sigma:a\mapsto{}a(0)+a(1)+\ldots$ that takes a sequence $a$ on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{R}$ to its infinite series and another function $s:k\mapsto{}a(0)+a(1)+\ldots+a(k)$ (associated to $a$) I can then say that $\sigma(a)=f\iff\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty}s(k)=f$. Is the topology you mentioned the one under consideration when talking about convergence of the sequence $s$?

Comment: @Teri I was addressing the motivation of the question, as given by the comment "*I'm asking what topology is being considered on the set of real functions when we talk about, for example, convergence of a power series*".  In such circumstances, we usually restrict our analysis to "nice" functions.  Perhaps it is more fitting to talk about $L^p(X)$ over compact $X \subset \Bbb R$, as this better reflects practice.

Comment: @user172061 a lot of the time, with power series in particular, mathematicians define convergence in terms of the $L^\infty([-a,a])$ norm.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, I just thought it worth mentioning. The main point everyone seems to be trying to convey is that user172061 is asking about the wrong space (for what seem to be his/her purposes)